# Why is x equal to 10?

Tags: c

For wrong password print "Incorrect password" and for correct password print "Correct password" and quit the program. The correct password is 1234.

I wrote code in C language and x needs a number to equalize. Why should we equalize x to 10 in the 3rd line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int pass, x=10; 
while (x!=0)
{
printf("\nInput the password: ");
scanf("%d",&pass);  

if (pass==1234)
{
    printf("Correct password");
    x=0;
}
else
{
   printf("Wrong password, try another");       
}
printf("\n");
}
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Are you saying that you wrote the code, but you don't know why you wrote `x=10`?

Comment: Yeah,i did not know.

Comment: @LeeJenkins That's a good one

Comment: One possibility is that the code is supposed to give you only ten tries to get the password right.

Comment: I tried more than 10 times,but i can get the correct password.

Comment: @Kheyraddin Look through the code and describe to yourself how x is being used. Does the value of x change during the execution of the program? If so, does the change of value affect the program in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Your code asks for a password until you type it in correct. To realize this you implemented the "flag" `x`.
 In each try you check if `x` is not equal to 0, if so run again. If the password is correct you set `x` to 0. Therefore `x` should be initalized with any value except for 0 to have at least one try.
`int x = 10;` could also be replaced by any other non zero value. 
If you want to add a limited number of tries (for example 10) you could modify your while-loop like below:

```
while (x!=0)
{
    printf("\nInput the password: ");
    scanf("%d",&pass);  

    if (pass==1234)
    {
        printf("Correct password");
        x=0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong password, try another"); 
        x--; //decrement your number of available tries     
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note: 
If you want to implement a password check, please never ever save passwords as plain text.

Comment: In the last you should add `printf("Entered wrong password 10 times, you are now locked out\n");`